# How to find documents by ObjectId?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have the following document in a mongodb collection

```
{
  "_id" : "52bbd9bef2ba1f37f4f010c1",
  "Name" : "Some Name",
  "TypeId" : 1
}
```

I now want to edit this document using the c# driver

```
BsonDocument doc = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", doc["_id"])); 
UpdateBuilder ub = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Set('Name', 'New Name');
WriteConcernResult updatedBook = _collection.Update(query, ub);
if (!updatedBook.UpdatedExisting)
{
   // I always end here
}
```

It is also weird that the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/) tell that `_collection.Update(query, ub)` should return a `BsonDocument` while they return a `WriteConcernResult`. Anyway if I use another property then `_id` I find the record.

It seems MongoDB is expecting a `ObjectId()` function wrapper around a `ObjectId`, isn't it? At least I need this in my tests while using `MongoVUE`.

**Edit**

If I try to find a record with this query

```
{
  "_id" : "52bbd9bef2ba1f37f4f010c1"
}
```

I get nothing. If I use this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52bbd9bef2ba1f37f4f010c1"),
}
```

it worked. So much for the Javascript way. AFAIK I have two ways to update a record with the native .net driver:

```
FindAndModifyResult

WriteConcernResult
```

But both ways expecting a `BsonValue` as value where `ObjectId` seems not to be a valid one...

So I tried using

IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", doc["_id"]));

as described above but that is the same like

```
{
  "_id" : "52bbd9bef2ba1f37f4f010c1"
}
```

So I wonder how to update a document by it's `ObjectId`?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but: `new ObjectId(doc["_id"])` in the Query?

Comment: @WiredPrairie `IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(doc["_id"])));` is not valid. Basically I don't know how to update a document that I identify by it's ObjectId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the currently available Nuget published MongoDB driver for .NET, I can confirm that this code as an example works properly:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(); // connect to localhost
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("test");
MongoCollection examples = test.GetCollection("examples");

string id = "52bc958ca45026c2ff24f90b";
IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));        
UpdateBuilder ub = Update.Set("Name", "George");
WriteConcernResult updatedBook = examples.Update(query, ub);
```

Using this collection data:

```
> db.examples.remove()
> db.examples.insert({Name:"Larry"})
> db.examples.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52bc958ca45026c2ff24f90b"), "Name" : "Larry" }
```

Then, run the C# code above and check the collection again:

```
> db.examples.find() 
{ "Name" : "George", "_id" : ObjectId("52bc958ca45026c2ff24f90b") }
```

While the `WriteConcernResult` class itself isn't a `BsonDocument`, the `Response` property contains the response from the command.

I also removed the unnecessary `Query.And`, as it's doesn't do anything when there's only one condition:

```
query = { "_id" : ObjectId("52bc958ca45026c2ff24f90b") }    
ub = { "$set" : { "Name" : "George" } }
```